# Exporting Dates to CSV

Tags: export-to-csv, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I can't figure out why the result of the export ( as csv ) has the forward slashes removed when viewing in excel. This options seems to work but the resulting data shows dates like this  ' 2 21 1991 7 26 1989 '

```
  exporterFieldCallback: function (grid, row, col, input) {
         if (col.colDef.type == 'date')
                     input = $filter('date')(input, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
                    return input;
            },
```

Please let me know what I am missing here

http://plnkr.co/edit/iJRhjy0nXR4P1xVVDRZd?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but it seems that since it was date format excel pigeonholed it into a date format which didn't include the format I was trying to display.

I made 1 change to make this work: adding single space around the field to force it to be a general field.

```
exporterFieldCallback: function (grid, row, col, input) {
     if (col.colDef.type == 'date')
                 input = ' '+$filter('date')(input, 'MM/dd/yyyy') +' ' ;
        },
```